# SPSS: trying to summarise the ranking of items, from a survey with drag&drop question

Tags: statistics, pivot-table, spss

I get the following data from a survey, with just a drag&drop question to rank favorite brands, between BMW, Mercedes, and Audi:

| BMW | Mercedes | Audi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

With SPSS, I need to output a table of counts for Rank vs. Brand, such as:

| Rank x Brand | BMW | Mercedes | Audi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Please help me writing the relevant syntax for the command.

I already tried multiple commands, using `FREQUENCIES` and also tried to group variables, with `multiple response sets`, etc.
I just get partial frequencies and was never able to articulate any `CROSSTABS` neither from my 3 variables.
Maybe I should create additional variables with formulas but cannot figure out how...
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CUSTOM TABLES for this analysis, you can restructure the datat to make it a regular table easier to analyse:

```
varstocases /make rnk from BMW Mercedes Audi/index=brand(rnk).
```

From here you can use regular analysis, for example:

```
aggregate out=* /break=model rnk/n=n.
```

or to get results in the output:

```
sort cases by model.
split file by model.
freq rnk.
split file off.
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the varstocase command.

Answer (score 1):

John K. Peck found an elegant solution, elsewhere:

```
CTABLES
  /TABLE BMW + Mercedes + Audi
  /CLABELS ROWLABELS=OPPOSITE.
```